# Can I make an item from a ListView show beyond the container limits?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

on my screen I have a transparent container on top and below I have a ListView with Cards. 
Now when i scroll down the list obviously the items on top of the list get cut off and disappear. 
Is there a way to scroll and have these items visible through the transparent container (therefor out of the normal limits of the container)?

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: 200,
                child: Center(child: Text('Transparent Box'))),
            Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(child: Text(items[index]));
                }))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I tried using a Stack, but then the ListView container shows through the transparent box from the beginning. But i still want the 'starting point' to be below that box. I hope you can follow my thoughts and explanation. 
Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your container and ListView to stack, then add top padding to list like this:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(child: Text(items[index]));
            })),
            Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            height: 200,
            child: Center(child: Text('Transparent Box'))),
      ],
    ));
```